# How to add users and passwords to a local cloudify deployment

Tags: cloudify

I am following the Cloudify user guide - its pretty easy to follow, and have installed a local deployment successfully.

Now I want to add users and passwords to the web management interface, how to do this? By default, the web interface supports anonymous login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your aim is to obtain full control over deployments, use the [Cloudify shell](http://www.cloudifysource.org/guide/2.1/qsg/quick_start_guide#step1) (or "Cloudify CLI").

As the Cloudify shell currently exposes *read-only* operations, it does not require login details. Configuring secured access for the *REST API*, however, can be done using spring security (which will be documented soon).

Comment: how do I delete the anonymous user? also are you saying that the user i create (by logging in) cannot deploy apps? how do I create a user +password that has full control over the web console and can deploy apps as well?

Comment: kindly let me know when documentation for secured access for the REST API will be available? Thanks...